# NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_app_branch.course_id

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with a `course_id` in my `BranchSerializer`, when I request POST method in my RESTful API. 
All answers thankful in advance!

Code example, `serializers.py`:

```
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = ('address', 'latitude', 'longitude')


class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('type', 'value')


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    branches = BranchSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    contacts = ContactSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if 'branches' in validated_data:
            branches_data = validated_data.pop('branches')
        if 'contacts' in validated_data:
            contacts_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
        course = Course.objects.create(**validated_data)
        branches_list = []
        contacts_list = []
        print(contacts_data)
        print(branches_data)
        for branches_details in branches_data:
            branches_list.append(Branch.objects.create(
            course_id = course.id,
            **branches_details))
        for contacts_details in contacts_data:
            contacts_list.append(Contact.objects.create(
            course_id = course.id,
            **contacts_details))
        course.save()
        return course
```

Models.py:

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="branches")
    latitude = models.TextField()
    longitude = models.TextField()
    address = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.address)
```

> NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_app_branch.course_id

Comment: Could you please add your `models.py` ?

Comment: Just added, I'm hoping to have your assistance on this).

Comment: Could you help me ?